# How to check if Hibernate is using a database index while loading data

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, orm, sybase

I am using Java, Sybase ASE and Hibernate 4.1.2. In my project, loading some data from table is taking quite some time. I doubt the Hibernate queries are not using index. But I don't know how to verify it is using index on the tables? Please help

Comment: You will have to post some code, and create table statements to get some show and tell on this question. Alternative: Try the DBA forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable query loading, get the query you are interested in and check what [execution plan Sybas](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/queryprocessing45.htm)e gives you.

You also need to take into account bind parameter values as well because that might also affect the execution plan generation.

You can also [supply index hints with Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20023_1251/html/optimizer/X67009.htm), and JPA also defines a [portable API for giving index hints](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#setHint-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could specify an Index in the entity class. This is often done with foreign key columns.

**E.G** : If you have a foreign key column as follows,

```
public class Project
{
...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    private User user;
...
}
```

You could specify an index as follows.

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "project")
@Table(appliesTo = "project" ,indexes = @Index(columnList = "user", name = "user_index"))
@Entity
public class Project
{
 ..
```

Note : You could specify and index for non foreign key columns as well.

Hope this helps.